# Spring Authorization Server 1.0 sample federated-identity-authorizationserver gives invalid_token_response

Tags: spring-security, federated-identity, spring-authorization-server

I am trying out federated-identity-authorizationserver sample given in [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver).

I updated the yml files as required.
I was able to start auth server and  resource server.
While starting client I got provider issuer error which I resolved by updating client yml as below

```
   provider:
      spring:
        authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize
        token-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token
        #issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

I am able to start the messaging client and able to perform authentication with google but getting below error. I am getting same error if I try it with local auth server using user1/password credentials.

```
{"exception":"[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]","timestamp":1674192821362}
```

To get the error I added failureHandler as below otherwise I was getting too many redirects error.

```
    @Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
            oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/messaging-client-oidc").successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler()).failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler()))
        .oauth2Client(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
```

I also tried adding accessTokenResponseClient as below but error remains same and the accessTokenResponseClient to the client config but it is not getting invoked. I have authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient() and other relevant classes.

```
    .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                    oauth2Login
                    .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint ->  
                        tokenEndpoint  
                        .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient()))
        
            .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/messaging-client-oidc").successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler()).failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler()))
    .oauth2Client(withDefaults());
```

I am getting above error when I try with local auth server and Google as a federated auth server.

The debug trace from client just before the error. the code is matching the federated server code

```
2023-01-24T22:24:59.078+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-01-24T22:24:59.079+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc?code=DxWgpwZqmepYInMZ0lBZrboaEVULZYep8r2I9Kz6MM9rY-2O2Bg1wSMiKPhwMM2U2Uf9bvd2N9pMFXbB7mCKw4GlDULdgNSADjHOzXQxdEGRNPtRVBU7i6OKfkxCtB7i&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D
2023-01-24T22:24:59.092+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token
2023-01-24T22:24:59.095+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-24T22:24:59.096+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[DxWgpwZqmepYInMZ0lBZrboaEVULZYep8r2I9Kz6MM9rY-2O2Bg1wSMiKPhwMM2U2Uf9bvd2N9pMFXbB7mCKw4GlDULdgNSADjHOzXQxdEGRNPtRVBU7i6OKfkxCtB7i], redirect_uri=[http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2023-01-24T22:24:59.276+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-24T22:24:59.284+05:30 DEBUG 96239 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getResponse(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:195) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:181) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:95) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:77) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:56) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getResponse(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:170) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

The debug trace from auth server

```
2023-01-24T22:24:54.510+05:30  INFO 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-01-24T22:24:54.518+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid%20profile&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&nonce=FTOwMi9WPU3zHBPBrG2Jj-Dxm0udS_dLfI1I0TiN2Ws
2023-01-24T22:24:54.581+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-24T22:24:54.608+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid%20profile&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&nonce=FTOwMi9WPU3zHBPBrG2Jj-Dxm0udS_dLfI1I0TiN2Ws&continue to session
2023-01-24T22:24:54.609+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login
2023-01-24T22:24:54.615+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-01-24T22:24:54.625+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to sample.web.LoginController#login()
2023-01-24T22:24:54.627+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to sample.web.LoginController#login()
2023-01-24T22:24:54.627+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to sample.web.LoginController#login()
2023-01-24T22:24:54.627+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-01-24T22:24:54.630+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-01-24T22:24:54.632+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to sample.web.LoginController#login()
2023-01-24T22:24:54.647+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2023-01-24T22:24:54.889+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-01-24T22:24:54.889+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-24T22:24:56.340+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorization/google-idp
2023-01-24T22:24:56.351+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=12345&scope=openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&state=LiD_tN32DWHRqSqplicP6DmLk9oYl4_jcW0koqBe4uc%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/google-idp&nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck
2023-01-24T22:24:56.661+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/oauth2/code/google-idp?state=LiD_tN32DWHRqSqplicP6DmLk9oYl4_jcW0koqBe4uc%3D&code=4%2F0AWtgzh5Qn1pSQP9samBXt-s-A9NUT0LBaC0iwCps44rQnq1M7wVMG-bd5DQj_0HMaSLSRA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none
2023-01-24T22:24:56.743+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
2023-01-24T22:24:56.747+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-24T22:24:56.748+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[4/0AWtgzh5Qn1pSQP9samBXt-s-A9NUT0LBaC0iwCps44rQnq1M7wVMG-bd5DQj_0HMaSLSRA], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/google-idp]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2023-01-24T22:24:57.051+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-24T22:24:57.052+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] as "application/json;charset=utf-8"
2023-01-24T22:24:57.093+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
2023-01-24T22:24:57.094+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2023-01-24T22:24:57.118+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-24T22:24:57.118+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2023-01-24T22:24:57.125+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 856E5CB5EA53F6364793E21162F85AF2
2023-01-24T22:24:57.125+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy  : Replaced CSRF Token
2023-01-24T22:24:57.126+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [***@gmail.com], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=ao1nlr-mAYrpo3nU3ODFUQ, sub=107668940011151070771, email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=***, locale=en-GB, nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp75Udyj3805vIwRZpzku1-cRpiFpuMWsivqzRa9=s96-c, aud=[12345], azp=12345, name=*** *, exp=2023-01-24T17:54:57Z, family_name=*, iat=2023-01-24T16:54:57Z, email=***@gmail.com}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=856E5CB5EA53F6364793E21162F85AF2], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@46dcae35]
2023-01-24T22:24:57.126+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [***@gmail.com], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=ao1nlr-mAYrpo3nU3ODFUQ, sub=107668940011151070771, email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=***, locale=en-GB, nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp75Udyj3805vIwRZpzku1-cRpiFpuMWsivqzRa9=s96-c, aud=[12345], azp=12345, name=*** *, exp=2023-01-24T17:54:57Z, family_name=*, iat=2023-01-24T16:54:57Z, email=***@gmail.com}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=856E5CB5EA53F6364793E21162F85AF2], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]
Saving first-time user: name=***@gmail.com, claims={at_hash=ao1nlr-mAYrpo3nU3ODFUQ, sub=107668940011151070771, email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=***, locale=en-GB, nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp75Udyj3805vIwRZpzku1-cRpiFpuMWsivqzRa9=s96-c, aud=[12345], azp=12345, name=*** *, exp=2023-01-24T17:54:57Z, family_name=*, iat=2023-01-24T16:54:57Z, email=***@gmail.com}, authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]
2023-01-24T22:24:57.126+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid%20profile&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&nonce=FTOwMi9WPU3zHBPBrG2Jj-Dxm0udS_dLfI1I0TiN2Ws&continue
2023-01-24T22:24:57.129+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid%20profile&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&nonce=FTOwMi9WPU3zHBPBrG2Jj-Dxm0udS_dLfI1I0TiN2Ws&continue
2023-01-24T22:24:57.130+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [***@gmail.com], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=ao1nlr-mAYrpo3nU3ODFUQ, sub=107668940011151070771, email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=***, locale=en-GB, nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp75Udyj3805vIwRZpzku1-cRpiFpuMWsivqzRa9=s96-c, aud=[12345], azp=12345, name=*** *, exp=2023-01-24T17:54:57Z, family_name=*, iat=2023-01-24T16:54:57Z, email=***@gmail.com}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=856E5CB5EA53F6364793E21162F85AF2], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]
2023-01-24T22:24:59.025+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/authorize
2023-01-24T22:24:59.026+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [***@gmail.com], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=ao1nlr-mAYrpo3nU3ODFUQ, sub=107668940011151070771, email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=***, locale=en-GB, nonce=mEbeJ8BYMUG2snc7fQgr-BhvBd1Gw4SYIZsch6rp7Ck, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp75Udyj3805vIwRZpzku1-cRpiFpuMWsivqzRa9=s96-c, aud=[12345], azp=12345, name=*** *, exp=2023-01-24T17:54:57Z, family_name=*, iat=2023-01-24T16:54:57Z, email=***@gmail.com}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=856E5CB5EA53F6364793E21162F85AF2], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]
2023-01-24T22:24:59.074+05:30 DEBUG 96235 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc?code=DxWgpwZqmepYInMZ0lBZrboaEVULZYep8r2I9Kz6MM9rY-2O2Bg1wSMiKPhwMM2U2Uf9bvd2N9pMFXbB7mCKw4GlDULdgNSADjHOzXQxdEGRNPtRVBU7i6OKfkxCtB7i&state=2gTNT52oxL3kRqtnbA0vnXQzp3VrghJmLtVUNEtagRo%3D
```

Comment: Are you using the [messages-client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/messages-client) or have you written your own client to test login?

Comment: Thanks for replying . Yes. I am using same messages-client and  messages-resource samples along with  federated-identity-authorizationserver. I am getting a feeling that it has do with nimbus jwt library but not able to find exact error.  I am adding additional details to the question

Comment: The sample should work out of the box, assuming you've correctly configured Google client-id and secret in the sample. Make sure you use `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to launch the login flow on the client.

Comment: I am using **http://127.0.0.1:8080**

Comment: Also, make sure you've configured the correct `redirect-uri` on the Google side. Should be `http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/google-idp`

Comment: Yes. I have done that as mentioned in the sample.  This I am trying on Mac OS